# Wordpress - problem establishing a database connection, Access denied for user

Tags: wordpress

This is a wordpress question. I have an error "Error establishing a database connection". Access denied for user. (using password: YES).

Through CPanel I changed the password for the user under the "Current Users".
Let's say that in my wp-config.php file there was:

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'coded_wp782' );

/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'coded_wp782' );

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'flke7djefd' );
```

When I changed the password for the user coded_wp782 through CPanel, the DB_PASSWORD in the above wp-config.php did not change but remained flke7djefd. I guess that flke7djefd is a coded version of what I put in through CPanel. How can I solve this? Should I put the uncoded password directly in the wp-config.php file? - I do not feel comfortable doing that. I also tried creating a new user and adding it to the database but it did not work, and the wp-config.php file did not change.

Comment: have you checked the host and have you check the privileges of that user?

Comment: Yes. I had this setting working for me, but yesterday I think I got hacked (posted about it here yesterday), so I changed my password and want my site to be working again.

Comment: put the password directly in - If they can access the wp-config file, nothing would stop them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Did you selected MD5 function on user_pass when changing the password in the database?